# Excel VBA .Autofilter Field:= Affects Wrong Column

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am currently working with some macros and I am puzzled with this piece of VBA code that I recopied.  This problem only occurs in this workbook alone and does not occur in other workbooks.  The issue is with this line:

```
sh1.Range("$A$21:$ZZ$10000").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="<>"
```

`.AutoFilter Field:=64`      Does not actually filter the 64th column.  When the macro is run, it affects the 65th column instead.

```
Sub FilterGate()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Program Management")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Certification")


sh1.Range("$A$21:$ZZ$10000").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("A1").Select

sh2.Range("$A$21:$ZZ$10000").AutoFilter Field:=64, Criteria1:="<>" 
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

**Why is the autofilter acting as such?**

Comment: Your code works for me. You probably have a missing column in sh1: `Field:=64` is Column **BL**

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just now tested the code on a fresh Excel workbook and it works properly as well no issues.  While I do not believe I am missing a column, the line of code still works on my original workbook, albeit not properly.  Based on the code, Column BL should be the right one except Column BM is what is actually filtered.

Comment: Is column A blank on that sheet?

Comment: Yes Column A is blank!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful posts everyone!  The issue was column A being completely blank.  The AutoFilters started from columns B to BO which is what threw off the numbers.  Starting the AutoFilters from columns A to BO helped fixed the problem.